# Xubuntu is not seeing my Win8 OS in the installer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, uefi, windows-8

When I install Xubuntu, I get the message "This computer currently has no detected operating systems. What would you like to do?". I just did a fresh install of Win8 yesterday, and I guess it used EFI because I have a 104MB partition that is of type 'efi'.

Is there any way to install Xubuntu next to Win8, and avoid any boot problems? Or can I switch Win8 to BIOS from EFI, without having to re-install Windows? I went through a ton of boot problems and re-installing yesterday... I really don't want to have to do it again.

Comment: What do you have now? Windows and Xubuntu or Xubuntu and Windows or just Xubuntu?  You should always install Windows _first_ before Linux, to avoid GRUB problems.

Comment: I have a fresh copy of Windows 8, that's it.

Comment: Ok,  Can you tell us what computer you have?

Comment: It's critical that we understand your current configuration. The Boot Info Script (http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) will track it down and save it in a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Try running the script and posting a link to its output.

Comment: This discussion and the tool `fixparts` helped me: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2126265

Answer (score 1):

1. Your PC is UEFI, so to avoid problems, you must use Xubuntu **12.10 64bit**
2. Use the Windows tools to reduce your Windows partition. Make at least 20GB free.
3. If the Xubuntu installer does not detect Windows, do **NOT** choose "Use the entire disk" option or it will erase Windows. Instead, use the "Somethingelse" option, create a root and a SWAP partition in the free space. (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace ), and install Xubuntu. Then use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s Recommended Repair to add a valid Windows UEFI entry in your GRUB menu.

Comment: On the download site 64bit is called 'AMD64'